# how do I add a Link in the n'th location of a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

Im using my own linked list, can anyone show me how to add a new link to the list in a specific location? say I wanted to do .add(3,4) so it would add the element 4 in the 4'th link of the list (since 0 is the first)?  (I dont want to use the LinkedList from the API, i know there is a method for doing this in there)

```
//Doubly linked list of integers

public class DLinkedList {
DLink _firstLink;
DLink _lastLink;
public DLinkedList()
{

}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (_firstLink==null);
}

public void addFirst(int e)
{
    DLink newLink = new DLink(e);
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        _lastLink = newLink;
    }
    else
    {
        _firstLink._previous = newLink;
    }
    newLink._next = _firstLink;
    _firstLink = newLink;
}

public void add(int index, int e)
{
    //how do I add a DLink in the i'th spot of the linked list?
}

public void addLast(int e)
{
    DLink newLink = new DLink(e);
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        _firstLink = newLink;
    }
    else
    {
    _lastLink._next = newLink;
    newLink._previous = _lastLink;
    }

    _lastLink= newLink;
}
}
```

Comment: You have to iterate to that position and replace the links, previous and next of the nodes.

Comment: at least try something.

Comment: He's new. Take it easy on him. Explain what he did wrong before down-voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void add(int index, int e)
{
    DLink iterator=_firstLink;
    int count=0;
    while(iterator!=_lastLink)
    {
         if(count>=index)break;
         iterator=iterator._next;
         count++;
    }
    if(index==count)
    {
        DLink newLink = new DLink(e);
        newLink._previous=iterator._previous;
        newLink._next=iterator;
        iterator._previous=newLink;
    }
    else throw new Exception("IndexOutOfBoundException");
}
```